# Which table are Aliases stored in?

Tags: sql-server, sitecore

In Sitecore I have created an alias called "bob" for a page.

[image: screenshot]

For most items in Sitecore, the data is saved in the `Items` table in the database.  You can easily see these if you search using the Item ID.

However whenever I search for an alias it returns no results:

```
select * from Items where ID ='0134A009-5D38-43C1-96C6-33C305543B7B'
```

**Are aliases stored in a different location?**

<sub>I have tried manually looking through all the tables and also ran a script which should search the whole database.  If it is stored there then it looks like it is not in plain text.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aliases like any other items are stored in the `Items` table.

You should check if you're looking for the Alias in the proper database. Maybe You're checking `core` or `web` database instead of `master`?

I've created a `Bob` alias in my env and query below returns 1 row containing alias details:

```sql
SELECT
 *
FROM 
 [dbo].[Items] 
WHERE 
 ID = '03275C36-32CE-47F7-AD28-9D5D2649E934'
```

Comment: You're right.  You know what? I was looking at the wrong SQL Server instance.  So it looked exactly the same.

Comment: I'm tempted to delete this question now.  It's not going to be helpful for anyone else.

Comment: I would leave the question as it is. There are no stupid questions, only the answers may be silly sometimes.